# How to send Dates to java springboot API and use those dates in a function

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sumAllHours", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> calcularhorastotais(
            @RequestParam(value = "startDate", defaultValue = "0") int startDate,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDate", defaultValue = "0") int endDate) {

                //get all from mongoDB between the dates choosen
                ArrayList<Documents> o = db.getDocumentsBetweenDateCreate(startDate,endDate);
                
                
                Date startDat = null; //Eclipse recomended to initialise var
                Date endDat = null;   //same
                 
                startDat.setDate(startDate);  //My idea to parse from string to date?
                endDat.setDate(endDate);  //  from the param


                double hours = 0;
                double total = 0;
                
                
                for(int i = 0; i != o.size(); i++) {  //Loop 
                
                //My idea here is to circle around all documents and do the calculations of how much time was spent
        
                hours = o.get(i).getStartHour() - o.get(i).getEndHour(); //to get the number of hours spent
                            
                total = total + hours; //sum everything
            }
                
                

                return new ResponseEntity<>(total, HttpStatus.OK); //output it


    }
```

My idea is to create an endpoint in my API that receives 2 dates, it goes to the mongoDB and gets all documents between those dates, ex : everything from 2010/01/01 until 2020/01/01,
then I want to do a for loop on those documents to sum up all the hours from each document, and in the end send that as the output of the function.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out this way:-

```
public String localDateTime(
      @RequestParam 
      @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") 
      final LocalDateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.toString();
  }
```

Or,

```
public void date(@RequestParam("date") 
      @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date) {
    }
```

or,

```
public void date(@RequestParam("date") 
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date date) {
}
```

There are other such ways, you can even configure at the Application level during Bean initialization.

**Note:-** ***You can also pass then as String from your client and accept into APIs and then use date formatter.***

Comment: The clients from this API can only send in String

Comment: Also I have every date in mongo already as 2021-07-12 19:14:22.159Z

Comment: Then pass input as String from your client and accept into APIs and then use date formatter.

Comment: @Query(value="{'dateProduct' : {$gte: ?0, $lte: ?1} }")
  public ArrayList<Products> getDocumentsBetweenDateProduct(Date startDate, Date endDate);